# Can I pass "new" anonymous function to addEventListener

Tags: javascript, events, arguments, anonymous-function

I use such code to pass arguments to event handler functions. But, in this particular case the loop is causing problems. Only the last linkTags[i] is accesible in all activeVisual calls. This has to do with the fact that the anonymous function that passes the argument is one and the same for the entire loop.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < linkTags.length; i++) {
    addCrossEvent(linkTags[i], "click", launchLink);
    addCrossEvent(linkTags[i], "mousedown", 
      function(evt) {
        activeVisual(evt, linkTags[i]);
      });
  }
```

Now, I remember trying to add new before the anonymous function declaration like this:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < linkTags.length; i++) {
    addCrossEvent(linkTags[i], "click", launchLink);
    addCrossEvent(linkTags[i], "mousedown", 
      new function(evt) {
        activeVisual(evt, linkTags[i]);
      });
  }
```

It did not work. The activeVisual never gets called. Can somebody explain to me why and how can I make it work, please?

UPDATE FINAL SOLUTION

Thanks to all responses below my WORKING code now looks like this:

```
  // Function that provides pass of event handling parameters with separate copy in each loop
  function callbackHandler(index) {
    return function(evt) {
      activeVisual(evt, linkTags[index]);
    }
  }
  ...
  for (var i = 0; i < linkTags.length; i++) {
    ...
    addCrossEvent(linkTags[i], "mousedown", callbackHandler(i));
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
addCrossEvent(linkTags[i], "mousedown", 
      (function(i) {
          return function(evt) {
              activeVisual(evt, linkTags[i]);
          }
      )(i);
);
```

The issue is with the iterator variable `i` which changes at each iteration, and a reference is passed of it, the value of `i` is not copied. Passing it this way as a parameter to a wrapper function, will cause a copy and it will receive the actual value at that particular iteration.

Comment: If the iterator i variable is the problem how come it does not cause problems in that line addCrossEvent(linkTags[i], "click", launchLink); ? Is it only passed by refference to anonymous functions?

Comment: because when you do addCrossEvent(linkTags[i], "click", launchLink); you have the value i in the linkTags array for each loop, but when the function is called on event, the i have the last value, and you got only the same position in the array

Comment: @avok00: In `addCrossEvent(linkTags[i], "click", launchLink)` you pass the value of `linkTags[i]` directly to the function. But `activeVisual(evt, linkTags[i]);` in the *callback* is evaluated when the callback is called, *not* in the loop. But when the callback is called, the loop has already finished and `i` has its final value.

Comment: Btw you are missing  a `}` to close the immediate function ;)

Comment: Yes, I see, I cannot understand what you did there, but it seems to work :) Can you explain what is this wrapper function you have used?

Comment: @avok00: It is just a function, that executes immediately (that is why it looks like `(function(index){...}(i))` *capturing* the current value of `i` (in the parameter `index` in my example). Remember that functions also have access to variables in "higher" scopes (that is the principle of closures) and here, the function that is returned from the immediate function (your event handler) has access to the "wrapper" functions scope and therefore to `index`. Instead of creating an immediate function, you could define that function beforehand, similar to my example with the object.

Comment: Thanks, you guys make me feel like I know nothing of javascript at all :) So this strange construct (function(index){...}(i)) actually makes it possible to pass parameters to an anonymous function? I will update my question with the final working code.

Comment: @avok00: Exactly. `index` the parameter defined in function and with `(i)` you pass the parameter. It is exactly like `function foo(index){...}; foo(i)` but substituting `foo` with its definition and putting parenthesis around it to make it more robust. Note that sometimes it can make a difference where you put the parenthesis. In my code  `new (function(index){...}(i))` does not work, but `new (function(index){...})(i)` does. But without `new` you should go with the first version.

Comment: @avok00: And no worries most of the stuff I learned only recently and if you want to have more insight into JavaScript, I recommend [High Performance JavaScript](http://www.amazon.com/Performance-JavaScript-Faster-Application-Interfaces/dp/059680279X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1292017898&sr=8-1) and [JavaScript Patterns](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Patterns-Stoyan-Stefanov/dp/0596806752/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1292017898&sr=8-5) (especially the last one). They helped me a lot, but you have to be familiar with the basic syntax and features (they are not for total beginners).

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here is an explanation why your way of using `new` does not work:

When you call a function with `new`, the function generates an empty object (which you can refer to with `this` inside the function and which inherits from the functions prototype) and returns it.
So you actually don't pass a function as callback handler, but the object returned by the function.

This is not a problem as long as the object implements the [`EventListner` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener) in order to be usable as event handler. If you do this, you could use your code with some modification:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < linkTags.length; i++) {
    addCrossEvent(linkTags[i], "click", launchLink);
    addCrossEvent(linkTags[i], "mousedown", 
      new (function(index) {
        this.handleEvent = function(evt) {
            activeVisual(evt, linkTags[index]);
        }
      })(i));
  }
```

This is actually similar to @Luca's answer, because the value of `i` is captured upon object creation. The upper code is actually identical to:

```
function CallbackHandler(index) {
    this.handleEvent = function(evt) {
        activeVisual(evt, linkTags[index]);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < linkTags.length; i++) {
    addCrossEvent(linkTags[i], "click", launchLink);
    addCrossEvent(linkTags[i], "mousedown", new CallbackHandler(i));
}
```

That said I find the usage of an immediate function that returns a function easier to read and I think using a function as event handler instead of an object is more common too.

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eGqg6/)

Comment: +1 For a very good solution and explanation. Sorry to say it does not work in IE8 maybe it does not understand this.handleEvent :(

Comment: @avok00: Maybe... IE is always a bit special ;) But the reason could also be that the `event` object has to be retrieved differently in IE. For more information about handling events and cross browser issues, read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html